# Group by using binary columns in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Getting an error of duplicate data when trying to perform a merge that uses a column of binary format

```
MERGE INTO  TARGET_TABLE tgt               
USING (         
      SELECT src.*
        FROM SRC_TABLE src
   ) src ON (NVL(tgt.brand,'N') = NVL(src.brand,'N')
        AND tgt.host = src.host 
        AND tgt.binary_col = src.binary_col )
  WHEN MATCHED AND (src.TOTAL_DISTINCT != tgt.TOTAL_DISTINCT 
OR src.TOTAL_DISTINCT_2 != tgt.TOTAL_DISTINCT_) THEN
      UPDATE
        SET tgt.TOTAL_DISTINCT=src.TOTAL_DISTINCT,
            tgt.TOTAL_DISTINCT_2=src.TOTAL_DISTINCT_2
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT(BRAND,   HOST,binary_col,TOTAL_DISTINCT,TOTAL_DISTINCT_2) 
          values(src.BRAND,src.HOST, 
  src.binary_col,src.TOTAL_DISTINCT,src.TOTAL_DISTINCT_2);
```

When I run the below code, I do get a count = 2 for a couple of my records.

```
SELECT nvl(src.brand,'N'), src.host, TO_CHAR(src.binary_col, 'HEX'), count(*)
  FROM src_table src
GROUP BY nvl(src.brand,'N'), src.host, TO_CHAR(src.binary_col, 'HEX')
HAVING count(*)> 1;
```

However when I try to find those individual records with below query, the query only returns 1 record for the ones that the group by returned 2.

```
SELECT src.*
FROM src_table src
WHERE 
 brand is null
 and host in ('www.myhost.com')
 and src.binary_col in ('6D5F2AC3300942F6A4CE066F056CAF0B'::BINARY)
```

Is there a workaround when using binary columns in merge/group by statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way to to quickly identify "duplicated" rows is usage of `QUALIFY` and windowed `COUNT`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(src.brand,'N'), src.host, TO_CHAR(src.binary_col, 'HEX'), *
FROM src_table src
QUALIFY COUNT(*) OVER (PARITITON BY COALESCE(src.brand,'N'), src.host,
                                    TO_CHAR(src.binary_col, 'HEX')) > 1;
```

This approach allows to quickly identify duplicates rows and do not collapse them like GROUP BY/HAVING approach.